# Mod_rewrite remove index and append query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site1/

RewriteRule ^(?:/(.*))?$ index.php?product=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm unable to get this mod_rewrite working. I get a 404 url not found whenever I have the appended query string on index. I'm trying to turn this:

http://www.domain.com/site1/index.php?product=mug

into this:

http://www.domain.com/site1/mug

Comment: If you specify that in `.htaccess` - then your url cannot start with `/`. Also, is your `.htaccess` located in the `site` subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, my .htaccess file is placed in the site1 subdirectory

Comment: @Phil - I'd like to keep my website in a subdirectory. Is there any way of implementing the rewrite rule while still maintaining the rewritebase structure?

Comment: The base of the rewrite rules when using per-directory configuration (`.htaccess`) is the directory containing said `.htaccess` file if it is a real path under the document root. See the documentation for [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

Comment: @zerkms - Your solution looks to be working great. Thanks a lot.